# Creating a timer and displaying it in a textbox (activated by a button)

Tags: java, timer, textfield

As far as I understand, it should be something as simple as this, however, I do not get any errors, nor does the program run.

```
public class test extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
  JTextField tf = new JTextField();
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  int counter = 30;

  public void init() {
  setLayout(null);
  tf.setBounds(10,10,100,40);
  tf.addActionListener(this);
  add(tf);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          public void run() {
            counter = counter - 1;
          }
        }, 2*60*1000, 2*60*1000);
    tf.setText(""+counter);
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 }
}
```

Please, bear in mind that I am a complete beginner, and YES, I did search around the web for a while, before coming here for help, and please, be as detailed as possible..

Any help / criticism is much appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have a main() without any code. This is where the app should be initialized:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test app = new test(); 
    app.init();
 }
```

Otherwise the `test` class will never open.

Comment: Thank you. The visualization is fixed, however, the functionality isn't running. (i.e. the countdown timer)

Comment: The logic of the timer doesn't really make sense. You are creating a JTextField and adding the timer into this through an actionListener. I think this timer should also be initialized within the init() method. Although I am not very familiar with Timers.